# how to get group of data with maximum rows count pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

for my dataframe i applied function group data by days and count number of rows , i want to get group with maximum number of rows

here i get rows count in each group:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,5,4,6],'x2':[5,5,6,7],
                         'time':['11/7/2019','11/7/2019',
                                 '11/7/2019','12/7/2019']}) 
xx = (pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])
       .dt.floor('d')
       .value_counts()
       .rename_axis('date')
       .reset_index(name='count'))
```

output target:

```
 x1  x2       timep
0   5   5  11/7/2019
1   5   5  11/7/2019
2   4   6  11/7/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform()`:

```
days= pd.to_datetime(df1['time']).dt.floor('d')
s = df1.groupby(days)['time'].transform('size')

df1[s == s.max()]
```

Output:

```
   x1  x2       time
0   5   5  11/7/2019
1   5   5  11/7/2019
2   4   6  11/7/2019
```